# TypeError: parametrize() got multiple values for argument 'indirect'

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-fixtures

I am trying to parametrize my pytest, by getting value from external function, my method is like that:

```
import pytest
from Utilities.MiscUtils import generate_random_email_for_registration
from Utilities.TextFileUtils import read_text_file


generate_random_email_for_registration()
```

Here `generate_random_email_for_registration()` will be generating random email address and storing it to Text file.

and my pytest mark goes like that:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("email", "password", [(read_text_file("email"), "Test@12345")], indirect=["email"])
```

`(read_text_file("email")` as this method, will be getting my value from email.txt file.

now while I execute , I am getting following error:

```
/Users/tp/AndroidPythonAppium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py:265: in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
/Users/tp/AndroidPythonAppium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py:80: in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
/Users/tp/AndroidPythonAppium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:272: in pytest_pycollect_makeitem
    return list(collector._genfunctions(name, obj))
/Users/tp/AndroidPythonAppium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:499: in _genfunctions
    self.ihook.pytest_generate_tests.call_extra(methods, dict(metafunc=metafunc))
/Users/tp/AndroidPythonAppium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py:292: in call_extra
    return self(**kwargs)
/Users/tp/AndroidPythonAppium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py:265: in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
/Users/tp/AndroidPythonAppium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py:80: in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
/Users/tp/AndroidPythonAppium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:151: in pytest_generate_tests
    metafunc.parametrize(*marker.args, **marker.kwargs, _param_mark=marker)
E   TypeError: parametrize() got multiple values for argument 'indirect'
```

I need to know, where I am making mistake, as this can be done by not using pytest.parametrize as well, but I am using good practice here.

Comment: what does `read_text_file("email")` return?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, it will be returning me random generated email address, which I have generated from generate_random_email_for_registration() method

Comment: so where is this fixture `email` defined that is being used for `indirect`?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the positional argument for indirect and passing it as a keyword argument only should fix this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("email, password", [(read_text_file("email"), "Test@12345")], indirect={"email"})
```